# Prototypes on WinJS.Binding.List projections

Tags: javascript, winjs

I'd like to be able to use a prototype method on a WinJS.Binding.List projection (e.g. createFiltered).

Example:

```
WinJS.Binding.List.prototype.shoutLength = function () {
    console.log("MY LENGTH IS " + this.length);
}


var list = new WinJS.Binding.List([2,1,3]);
var filtered = list.createFiltered(function (item) { return item <= 2; });

list.length; // outputs 3
filtered.length; // outputs 2

list.shoutLength(); // works
filtered.shoutLength(); // doesn't work (Object doesn't support property or method 'shoutLength')
```

What can I apply the prototype to so that it will work on filtered projections, sorted projections, grouped projections etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Methods such as `createdFilterd`, `createSorted`etc., create different objects as name suggest, 
so you'll need to extend those, in your case it would be:

```
WinJS.Binding.GroupedSortedListProjection,
WinJS.Binding.FilteredListProjection,
WinJS.Binding.SortedListProjection
```